# React native Fabric autolink error with react 60.0 and above

Tags: react-native, google-fabric

I have upgraded to my app to react-native 60.4 which support Autolinking all packages so that you dont have to manually go about setting things up and thus lowers the chances of error.

The problem is most of the packages have still not gotten compatible with this process and henceforth the app completely breaks.

my error is with https://github.com/corymsmith/react-native-fabric

referring to an issue on the repo for the same -> https://github.com/corymsmith/react-native-fabric/issues/225, which still remains unanswered.

I started giving it a try by forking the repo and understanding the auto link process given by react native.

In the package.json of the node_module package i replaced

```
"rnpm": {
    "android": {
     "packageInstance": "new FabricPackage()"
    }
},
```

with file in the package root react-native.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  dependencies: {
    'react-native-fabric': {
        platforms: {
            android: {
                "packageImportPath": "import com.smixx.fabric.FabricPackage;",
                "packageInstance": "new FabricPackage()"
            }
        }
    }
  }
};
```

I also updated the build gradle to 3.4.1 from 3.1.0

My react native app is able to now find the package.

But when i call the package in my react component i get NoClassDefFoundError, which means that class is not found.

Anybody else gave this a try and have a solution please let me know.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError error is a class that exists but is dependent. Check out the dependencies associated with this class.

Comment: It happens specifically when upgrading to gradle 3.4.1. The error when i call the package is ```FabricPackage missing```

Comment: Ok i got this to work by changing the forked repo, but i think the only scalable solution i see right now is to degrade to RN ^59.0 as not a lot of packages have auto link config changes. So will wait for RN 60.4 to mature and then upgrade to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to unlink with react-native unlink and then re run your code again.

Comment: It still dosent work as react-native-share still uses ```rnpm``` and RN^60.4 does not allow that. This needs to be changes to configs in ```react-native.config.js``` file at the root of the package with auto discovery and link configurations

Answer (score 1):

Putting it here from the above comment to make it more clear:

Ok i got this to work by changing the forked repo -> (adding a react-native.config.js in the root of the package with with auto discovery and link configurations), but i think the only scalable solution i see right now is to degrade to RN ^59.0 as not a lot of packages have auto link config changes. So will wait for RN 60.4 to mature and then upgrade to it in about a month. In addition to this fabric is currently migrating to firebase and plans to complete by year end. This mean that anyways the sdk integration is going to be obsolete and hence this package too.

Also this issue is majorly related to react-native-fabric and not RN itself.